# Compiling android emulator gives grpc missing

Tags: build, android-emulator, android-source, repo

I m trying to build Android s emulator: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu.git/+/refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release

I cloned the entire AOSP source and added some missing packages to the default.xml from repo, here they are:

```
  <project name="platform/external/qemu" path="external/qemu" revision="791783c6e74c936a8fcd231ad36219385723bb8a" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qemu-android-deps" path="prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qemu-android-deps" revision="715d3bed0a3dc4f9980528c9bfb81469f2d3cbab" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/common" path="prebuilts/android-emulator-build/common" revision="180c9a42b79f9c22a38f902564ea3950d4460a96" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qt" path="prebuilts/android-emulator-build/qt" revision="23cbd79e9db666af535e2cefcb23fcdf0ff0c123" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/mesa" path="prebuilts/android-emulator-build/mesa" revision="be7c00f399b415511d73308f0af0c0310512aced" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/mesa-deps" path="prebuilts/android-emulator-build/mesa-deps" revision="17837fdb1889014fa01cbbbda56afc9b6034815f" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/curl" path="prebuilts/android-emulator-build/curl" revision="06f0905068b9ebfdd2d11b4d310c36b68c2fbe2f" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/archive" path="prebuilts/android-emulator-build/archive" revision="0545d85d4442d77841f8a81ecd2627aff175ce02" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/prebuilts/android-emulator-build/protobuf" path="prebuilts/android-emulator-build/protobuf" revision="8e2a5472dd374e6c971d30eb3d00898a8c1a25c8" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
  <project name="platform/external/grpc-grpc" path="external/grpc" revision="0d80ea35ba09d0462ca13f236cc9ddc3fb749c57" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
```

I added all of them when I noticed they missing when trying to compile by running `android/rebuild.sh` on the `platform/external/qemu` repo. Until I arrived at this error:

```
CMake Error at android/android-grpc/CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory given source
  "/home/project/disk/aosp/grapheneos-lz_experiments/external/qemu/../grpc/emulator"
  which is not an existing directory.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There s no `platform/external/grpc` repo, but there is `platform/external/grpc-grpc` which as you see below, I made appear at the path `external/grpc`:

```
  <project name="platform/external/grpc-grpc" path="external/grpc" revision="0d80ea35ba09d0462ca13f236cc9ddc3fb749c57" upstream="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" dest-branch="refs/heads/aosp-emu-30-release" groups="pdk" clone-depth="1"/>
```

Would be nice to know why the repo isn t named just `grpc` instead of `grpc-grpc` or why the compiler does not try to load from `grpc-grpc` instead of `grpc`